# Is it possible to force Android Wifi to 802.11a/b/g or disable 802.11n from within an app?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have developed an Android app that needs to connect to a Windows hotspot.  When the Windows hotspot is allowed to use 802.11n the Android device is constantly disconnecting and reconnecting to the hotspot.

Is it possible, from WITHING MY APP (no rooting / settings changes / whatever else) to either force 802.11a/b/g (all or one) OR disable 802.11n?

I've been looking through the Android documentation and searching, but so far have had no luck finding an answer.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: Might be nice if someone answered this question with more than a comment.